# Choosing Specific Year when using EXTRACT

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to pull a few SUMs, but I'm getting stuck on how to narrow it down to a specific year.

I have the following code...

`SELECT SITE_ID,
  Extract(YEAR FROM DATE_ORDERED) YEAR,
  Extract(MONTH FROM DATE_ORDERED) MONTH,
  SUM(TOTAL_PRICE),
  SUM(TOTAL_PRICE),
  SUM(TOTAL_SAVINGS)
FROM DB.ACTUAL_SAVINGS_MVIEW
WHERE SITE_ID = 561
GROUP BY SITE_ID,
  Extract(YEAR FROM DATE_ORDERED),
  Extract(MONTH FROM DATE_ORDERED)
ORDER BY YEAR DESC,
  MONTH DESC`

This returns all available years, when I'm only looking for 2016.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are not limiting by year in the where clause

Comment: I'm unbelievable hahaha... Sorry.. it's been a long day...

Comment: `Extract(YEAR FROM DATE_ORDERED)` will probably not use any index/partitioning, better use a searchable condition: `DATE_ORDERED BETWEEN DATE '2016-01-01' and DATE '2016-12-31'`

Answer (score 3):

How about adding it to your where clause:

```
SELECT SITE_ID,
  Extract(YEAR FROM DATE_ORDERED) YEAR,
  Extract(MONTH FROM DATE_ORDERED) MONTH,
  SUM(TOTAL_PRICE),
  SUM(TOTAL_PRICE),
  SUM(TOTAL_SAVINGS)
FROM DB.ACTUAL_SAVINGS_MVIEW
WHERE SITE_ID = 561
AND Extract(YEAR FROM DATE_ORDERED) = 2016
GROUP BY SITE_ID,
  Extract(YEAR FROM DATE_ORDERED),
  Extract(MONTH FROM DATE_ORDERED)
ORDER BY YEAR DESC,
  MONTH DESC
```

Comment: Yea... I can't believe I missed that... long day must have me losing my mind... I feel stupid now hahaha.. thanks for this